# How to make button do some work(write a method) as well as show a pop up window

Tags: java, android, popup

To show a pop up window i used this way :

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finish) ;

b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Pop.class));
    }
});
```

code of pop.java

```
public class Pop extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceSate) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceSate);

    setContentView(R.layout.popup);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics() ;
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels ;
    int height = dm.heightPixels ;

    getWindow().setLayout( (int)(width*.6),(int)(height*.4) ) ;
```

I want my button to do some work too as soon as it is pressed so where should i write the method for that and can i use onclick() for that ? 
Thank You :)

Comment: if any of the answers below responds to your question, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code snippet must be placed inside the `onCreate()` callback of the calling activity (in your case it seems MainActivity), after the `setContentView()` call.

If you need to display a popup I suggest you to use Dialogs https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

You can write your method after the onClick, before changing the activity or within the new activity in the onCreate method.